# Firebird 2.5 query returns COLLATION UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT for CHARACTER SET UTF8 is not installed

Tags: utf-8, firebird, database-restore, firebird2.5

I have an old source database in which apparently custom collation `UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT` was created. I'm running it on docker via image `jacobalberty/firebird:2.5-ss`. Originally database was created on a Windows machine.

When I try to do a query on the table where this collation was used, I get the error:

```
SQL> select * from "InvoiceService";
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 22021
COLLATION UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT for CHARACTER SET UTF8 is not installed
```

Show collations returns the following:

```
SQL> show collations;
UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT, CHARACTER SET UTF8, FROM EXTERNAL ('UNICODE'), CASE INSENSITIVE, ACCENT INSENSITIVE, 'NUMERIC-SORT=1'
```

I tried the following fixes:

1. add entry to `fbintl.conf`:

```
<charset UTF8>
    intl_module fbintl
    collation   UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT
</charset>
```

Then run the `sp_register_character_set("UTF8", 4)` procedure, and receiving error about duplicate collations (because UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT is already defined in the DB).

2. Dropping collation

```
SQL> drop collation UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 42000
unsuccessful metadata update
-Collation UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT is used in table InvoiceService (field name NAME) and cannot be dropped
```

3. Adding new column in which different collation would be used, but can't even add it:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLE "InvoiceService" ADD NAME2 VARCHAR(600) CHARACTER SET UTF8;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 22021
unsuccessful metadata update
-InvoiceService
-COLLATION UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT for CHARACTER SET UTF8 is not installed
```

4. With using `gbak` restoring only metadata, fixing the schema and then inserting only the data, but `gbak` does not support restoring data only

...

I'm out of ideas now. What else could I try?

Comment: Attempting to register the UTF8 character set makes no sense, because it already exists in your database. IIRC, UTF8 collations do not need to be registered in fbintl.conf, as those are applied automatically from the ICU library. And the definition you have won't work any way, because that would require ICU to have a collation with that exact name, while it is only the name given to it in your database. My first guess would be that there is a problem with the ICU library in the image. I'll try to some things to see if I can find out what's going on here.

Comment: It might make sense to ask your question on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support) as well.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I was thinking that the problem might be that collation was created on one server, then DB file was copied and I use it on a different machine/in Docker. So the current machine has no way of knowing what this collation is. But is there a way to somehow get at least raw data in bytes for this column?

Comment: Source DB was actually created on Windows.

Comment: Did you restore the database from backup, or did you just copy the database file? Transferring between platforms (in this case Windows to Linux) should be done by backup and restore.

Comment: Our common procedure until now was just copying the DB file as it worked until this case. I'll do backup/restore in the future. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Since a few years, in most situations it will seem to work, but if you have indexes that use collations then a backup and restore is necessary so the index is rebuilt using the ICU version installed on the target system. There might be other possible issues, though I can't think of it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I finally managed to solve the problem. What I did was to create a DB backup with

```
gbak -v -t -user SYSDBA /path/to/source.fdb /path/to/backup.fbk
```

Then use the 3.0 version of Docker image with Firebird DB (`jacobalberty/firebird:3.0`) and restore from backup with

```
gbak -create /path/to/backup.fbk /path/to/restored3.fdb
```

*Note that the same backup-restore procedure without switching the Docker image did not work.*

I didn't have to do anything else. There's only a slight difference in `SHOW COLLATIONS;` output:

```
// originally:
UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT, CHARACTER SET UTF8, FROM EXTERNAL ('UNICODE'), CASE INSENSITIVE, ACCENT INSENSITIVE, 'NUMERIC-SORT=1'

// restored DB
UTF8_CI_AI_NUMERIC_SORT, CHARACTER SET UTF8, FROM EXTERNAL ('UNICODE'), CASE INSENSITIVE, ACCENT INSENSITIVE, 'COLL-VERSION=58.0.6.50;NUMERIC-SORT=1'
```

Comment: If going to Firebird 3.0 fixed it, then I guess something is wrong with ICU in the Firebird 2.5 image.

Comment: Something is wrong with whole INTL module in Firebird 2.5. It shouldn't be used for advanced things like this one.

Comment: As a side note, restored DB then works fine with Firebird 2.5

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! Had the same problem and creating/restoring a backup of the .fdb *using the same Firebird installation removed the COLLATION error